# Robocopy permission issue

Tags: access-control-list, ntfs, robocopy

I'm using [robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.10).aspx) to sync files between two different servers (one of them is not a Windows server but exposes Windows-like shares); but I'm having a permission issue.

I need to replicate all contents and also keep existing ACLs; I'm using a command like this:

```
robocopy.exe \\server1\share \\server2\share /mir /copyall
```

However, the user account which runs this command has only ***read*** access to some folders; this leads to an interesting problem: after the first sync, the same permissions are applied to the copied folders... and thus *the user account loses write access to those folders* and can't update them anymore.

Is there any way to avoid or fix this?

Comment: There is no fix because it's not broken. The behaviour you encounter is quite to be expected. What OS is the target system?

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2. And I know everything is working as it should... however the end result is unusable.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to use an Administrator or Backup user account and perhaps also pull the source from the target.

Comment: I'm already pulling the source from the target, and I'm using a local administrator account; but the ACLs often don't include "Administrators", thus the user account can't access folders where it doesn't have explicit permissions.

Comment: But the administrator can always access any file, regardless of the actual ACL. Are you running the script in elevated mode?

Comment: No, and yes. The administrator can take ownership of files and folders and can reset ACLs, but can't acually access anything if the ACLs say "no".

Comment: Unfortunately, changing ACLs after Robocopy is done would be useless here, because they would be reset on the next run (and also, because as soon as a folder is created with the wrong permissions, the user running Robocopy can't even copy its *contents* in it).

Comment: Have you tried in backup mode?  `/b`, or `/zb`, which uses the special backup privilege that allow it to bypass ACLs?

Comment: @Zoredache This effectively solves the issue; please post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robocopy includes an option `/b` that activates and uses the [special Backup privileges](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn221961.aspx) that allow the process to bypass access controls.  Assuming default rights assignments, you need to be running as an administrator, server operator, or backup operator to use this option.  The `/zb` option tells robocopy to only use the backup mode when needed.